# My csproj.user file in multiple repos gets frequently corrupted aftering closing VS2017. What's going on?

Tags: git, visual-studio, corruption

I wasn't sure if this would fit better here in StackOverflow or over in [Super User](https://superuser.com/), but I'll start here since it's mostly dev tools related to this.

When I open a project in VS2017, I'll sometimes run into this:

[image: Image of error in user file when trying to load project]

When I open the user file, I see this:

[image: Image of character corruption on last closing tag of XML file]

The character corruption is random, and always at the close of the file. Sometimes the filename itself will become corrupted. When I correct the closing tag, the project loads normally and it's fine. And it'll load several more times without issue. But a couple weeks later, it happens again. It's very intermittent.

The corruption seems to be generated upon closing Visual Studio, but not consistently. It's almost always the `*.csproj.user` file, and it has happened in many different projects.  I have no clue what's causing this.

I say "almost always" because this has also happened:

[image: Image of the VS error list showing a character corruption in the filename of a obj\Debug file]

I've included some system info below to help out, but I'm largely clueless here. It's worth noting that this corruption does happen without the Oracle add-on, but I'm not sure if ReSharper is a culprit yet. Just hoping someone else has seen this and figured it out.

Thanks!

---

- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise 1709 16299.847
- IDE: Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 15.9.4 (complete install)
- Add-ons: ReSharper Ultimate 2018.2.3 9/12/18, Oracle Dev Tools 18.3.0
- SC: git 2.14.2.windows.2 using Git Bash

This is a work machine with all the usual enterprise fixins: endpoint antivirus, doc scanning, etc. I have a ticket open with them, too, but I have a feeling they're going to suggest wiping my machine and starting over-- not wild about that solution.

Comment: How old is your hard drive?

Comment: My box has 2 Samsung SSDs from 2015 (not in RAID). https://us.hardware.info/product/317509/samsung-pm871-512gb/specifications